# Целесообразность использования массива Numbers

Tags: java

Есть класс MatrixTools, который должен проводить с матрицами разного рода операции (нахождение максимального элемента, вычеркивание нулевых строк, и т.п.). Он должен работать как с int элементами, так и с float. Отсюда вопрос. Как лучше хранить матрицу, как массив Numbers, чтобы писать меньше кода, или отдельно хранить матрицу int-ов и матрицу float? Если хранить как массив Number, то как сравнивать элементы matrix между собой?

P.S.Только без Generics

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать Generics?

Comment: задание из главы до generics

Comment: Тогда кастуйте к одному какому-то типу, например, float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем работнику с матрицей её хранить, тем более в виде сырого массива? Сделайте Generic-класс Matrix, реализуйте его(или возьмите его из стандартной библиотеки Java; рекомендую именно так), а при сравнении используйте именно методы переданной в работника матрицы. Как сравнивать int и float? Либо округлять, либо кастовать к одному типу, либо использовать фичи Generic.

Comment: надо без generics

Comment: У вашего заказчика до того старая Java?

Comment: ахах, ок, понял)